# The console tag should not be a synonym of terminal

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console) is a synonym of [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal). But [console is a subset of terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-cons), and it's a useful one. For example, [console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console) the right tag for [this OpenBSD question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-to-change-usb-keyboard-encoding-in-console), and for several prior Linux questions — they shouldn't be lost amongst the more generic [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) questions.

I haven't seen “console” used to mean the more general terminal concept much, so I don't think the synonym is warranted due to popular confusion. (There are certainly many more questions confusing “terminal” and “shell”, and these are very different topics.)

So please remove the [console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console) synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's had 26 renames; is the distinction between the two really important? Are there people that care about [console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console) questions but not [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) questions?

---

**Edit**: Ok, I pulled it

Comment: Yes, there is a clear distinction, but perhaps not everyone is aware of it.  Configuring the console is different from configuring a terminal, so having separate tags would help filter out all unrelated questions, assuming the tag is used correctly.

Comment: People who would subscribe: probably not. For searching, it's valuable. Quick, tell me how to find all the questions about the Linux console. Ok, it's [not so bad](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal+linux) because there's someone who actively removes the linux tag from non-linux-specific questions, but [tag:console] would scale better. (And 26 renames? I suspect I've done more `terminal`→`shell` retags than that.)

Comment: @Gilles I realize it would *let* you find questions about the console; I'm asking if that's actually important. Is it a common need to find all questions about Linux consoles but not about terminals in general? We have to weigh that against the odds that without the synonym, people are likely to tag questions incorrectly (and that's not even factoring `shell` into this, which is probably even worse) -- is it worth the added overhead of manually keeping them straight?

Comment: If there are people asking, there are (or should be, but we tag because we assume there are) people searching. Also, it's easier to periodically go over the smaller `console` tag and retag the generalizable questions, than to go over the larger `terminal` tag and retag the specialized questions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.

`console` is the physically attached keyboard and screen, `terminal` is a remote terminal or a terminal emulator such as `xterm`.

console is likely to be `linux`, terminal is likely to be `putty` or `xterm`.  Configuring them is quite different.

Comment: idk, I've mostly felt `console` and `terminal` are interchangeable terms... which may refer to different things... but like `geek` and `nerd` the precise meaning depends on who you ask. Such as I think `Virtual Terminal` means similar to `console` but is obviously not an `xterm`.